# Blurring an image tile-by-tile

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to segment an input image and blur it tile-by-tile, but after all `cv::blur` invocations on adjacent tiles I've got border pixels, which differ from what I've got when collectively applying `cv::blur` to the whole image at once.

```
Mat upper(im, Rect( 0,0, 10,10 ));
Mat lower(im, Rect( 0,11, 10,20 ))

blur( upper, upper, Size( 5, 5 ) );
blur( lower, lower, Size( 5, 5 ) );
```

It looks like the library version I use (2.4.8) doesn't do what I expect reading through the following:

> Unlike the earlier versions of OpenCV, now the filtering operations **fully support** the notion of image ROI, that is, **pixels outside of the ROI but inside the image can be used in the filtering operations**.

(Taken from: [See FilterEngine::apply description here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html))

P.S.1: I've tried to extract the `cv::boxFilter` implementation and change the `srcRoi` parameter value, but have wrong results either.

```
Mat src = im.clone();
Mat dst = src; // Trying to perform the operation in-place

Size ksize( 5, 5 );
Point anchor(-1,-1);

Ptr<FilterEngine> f = createBoxFilter( 
  src.type(), dst.type(),
  ksize, anchor, true, BORDER_DEFAULT 
);

f->apply( 
  src, dst, 
  Rect(0,0,10,10), 
  Point(0,0), false 
);
f->apply( 
  src, dst, 
  Rect(0,0,10,10), 
  Point(0,11), false 
);
```

P.S.2: Help on coloring the source code would be helpful.

Comment: P.S.3 was my fav. console. Just Saying :D However, what do you mean by *'coloring the source code'*

Comment: Note: adding a language tag fixes your syntax colouring.

Comment: To @PaulR: My reputation level is too low, to add C++ tag.

Comment: To @MrCoder: I used to program PS3 a bit in the past. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is because you are trying to do this in-place. Once you've blurred part of the image then you have invalidated source pixels that would be needed for blurring any adjacent part of the image. The solution is to not do this in-place, so that the original source pixels are available for whatever part of the image you want to blur.

Comment: Didn't think it's so simple. Thanks! By the way, don't you know the earliest version of OpenCV, which actually "sees" picture pixels beyond the boundaries of a ROI?

Comment: @parallelgeek: You could do it with overlapping tiles. Say tile size is 100px, and blur radius is 30px, then use 160px tiles every 100px, and discard the outer 30px from each edge. It's going to be significantly more computationally intensive, I guess, but it might help if you're having memory issues.